# adding Edittext and Button when clicking a button in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

my app needs an add button that adds two Edittext and another button every time they click the add button
adds again the same three things under the added ones, I attached a screenshot of how my app suppose to work, I really need help in this I am new in android development.

here is my activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Mark_calc">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/Mark_calcTB"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Box_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="207dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Mark_calcTB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Total_MarksTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Total marks:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Box_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_total_marksTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Mark_calcTB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="Total hours:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Box_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_total_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Box_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mark1"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Mark%"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Box_1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hours1"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Hours"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mark1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Box_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hours1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Box_1" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is a screenshot of [how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CA5p.png).

Comment: use recyclerview instead and on pressing add button increase the count and start notifydatasetchange.

Comment: Can you please show me how I am new in android development @HaiderSaleem

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719750/adding-items-in-recycleview-dynamically-using-a-button/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take Recyclerview and when you click on add Button add the data to your ArrayList and update the adapter to NotifyDataSetChanges.