# How to create a step-by-step instruction in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Create a step-by-step edit text with numbering for users to input with a button to add another edit text. edit text can be removed and the edit text can be sorted by moving it.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxKXi.jpg)

Comment: You can use `RecyclerView` for this type of layout.

Comment: @AndroidGeek any coding to refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Recycler View for this:

**For Example, follow below layout design:**

[image]

**Add below code in Main Layout(In Activity/Fragment Layout)**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**Add below code for setting adapter to Activity or Fragment**

```
    ArrayList<StepsModel> stepsModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    stepsModelArrayList.add(new StepsModel(" Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.",""));
    stepsModelArrayList.add(new StepsModel(" Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.",""));
    rvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    StepsRecyclerAdapter stepsRecyclerAdapter = new StepsRecyclerAdapter(this, stepsModelArrayList);
    rvMain.setAdapter(stepsRecyclerAdapter);
```

**Add StepsRecyclerAdapter.java file**

```
public class StepsRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StepsRecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder> {
    private static String TAG = StepsRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public static List<StepsModel> stepsList;
    public Context mcontext;
    View view;

    public StepsRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<StepsModel> uploads) {
        stepsList = uploads;
        mcontext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StepsRecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.item_steps, parent, false);
        return new StepsRecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StepsRecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int pos = position+1;
        holder.tvStepsPosition.setText(""+pos);

        holder.tvStepsDetails.setText(stepsList.get(position).getStepsDetails());
    }
    

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stepsList.size();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private TextView tvStepsPosition, tvStepsDetails;
        private ImageView ivStepsImage;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvStepsPosition = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStepsPosition);
            tvStepsDetails = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStepsDetails);
            ivStepsImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivStepsImage);
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Create Item Layout - item_steps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_circular"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStepsPosition"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStepsDetails"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="lorem"
                android:padding="10dp"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/finestGray"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivStepsImage"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_camera_alt_24"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Model Class - StepsModel**

```
public class StepsModel {
    String stepsDetails, stepsImages;

    public StepsModel() {
    }

    public StepsModel(String stepsDetails, String stepsImages) {
        this.stepsDetails = stepsDetails;
        this.stepsImages = stepsImages;
    }

    public String getStepsDetails() {
        return stepsDetails;
    }

    public void setStepsDetails(String stepsDetails) {
        this.stepsDetails = stepsDetails;
    }

    public String getStepsImages() {
        return stepsImages;
    }

    public void setStepsImages(String stepsImages) {
        this.stepsImages = stepsImages;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am using two strings in Model class `stepsDetails` - for Details of steps, `stepsImages` - for Image of steps, You can add this model class data to arraylist like - `stepsModelArrayList.add(new StepsModel(" Lorem ipsum may be used as a placeholder before final copy is available.",""));`

For more info related to RecyclerView, Check these links [link1](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview), [link2](https://medium.com/@suhanshupatel/recyclerview-in-android-for-beginner-cfbc132a0dec)

Adding Items in RecycleView Dynamically using a button - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719750/adding-items-in-recycleview-dynamically-using-a-button)

**Adding Items dynamically:**

```
 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stepsModelArrayList.add(new StepsModel());
                stepsRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: For the model part, besides, stringStepDetails, what should be added too? I havent run it but everything seems ok in coding just the part of the lorem ipsum, im wondering do i just add like String s1,s2? and adding it into s10? as maximum?

Comment: @AidenK,  If you have 10 steps then you need to add 10 Model class objects in arraylist and Please check edited anwser - Model class added to answer.

Comment: one more question. so if I wanna change the textview stepdetails into edittext stepdetails where each steps is different and needed to be in different String. i will just have to add 10 strings into the model right?

Comment: @AidenK Yes you are right.

Comment: I wasnt quite sure how to do the recyclerview dynamically using a button. If you can add on that to the coding you have done earlier. I would be much appreaciated.

Comment: @AidenK Okay, code added for adding dynamically items. Please Check this link  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719750/adding-items-in-recycleview-dynamically-using-a-button

Comment: I wanted to add the "steps details" into firebase as in step by step ( i think it needed loop for arraylist?) and show it later on another activity.

Comment: You can save data into firebase : 1. On change of text in edittext, on adding image, In this case you don't need any loop.
2. For second option, you need a button, In this case first you need to save whole data into your arraylist then you need a loop to save whole in firebase.
Out of these two cases, you can use one case in which you are more comfortable.

Comment: In this case, do I need to call "stepsDetails1" , "stepsDetails2'.... etc in my model? or just one "stepsDetails" is enough? and arraylist will do the rest?

Comment: Just one "StepsDetails" is enough in one object of model class.

Answer (score 0):

If it is dynamically increasing and decreasing, the best approach is `RecyclerView` 
Here is a simple RecycleView to get start with: [Simple RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584425/16793225)